# Print screen on first two clicks

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm in the starting phase of vba learning. i have written this code and it takes print screen and paste it to powerpoint after five seconds, i want to take print screen when i run my code it should two take print screen on first two clicks.
`Sub PrintScreen()
Sleep 5000
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
ActivePresentation.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutBlank
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
End Sub`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Sounds like they're wanting us to write their code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most OSes don't support inserting text randomly to a file, you will have to read each text line, modify it and write the modified text line to a file.

Here's an algorithm:

```
While reading the text line is good:  
  Prepend your text to the text line.  
  Write text line to new file.  
  end-while  
close files.
```

If you use `std::string`, you could lookup the `insert` method to help you.

Comment: The job isn't finished.  You then have to delete the original file, and rename the output file with the name of the original.

Comment: The OP may not want to change the original file, which is why I didn't mention that part.